# How to convert a string into a HTML element in Mithril?

Tags: html, string, mithril.js

Suppose I have a string `<span class="msg">Text goes here</span>`.I need to use this string as a HTML element in my webpage. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: It's totally clear what the author is asking. Further votes to close under that heading should try asking if they still don't get it.

Answer (score 11):

Mithril provides the [`m.trust`](https://mithril.js.org/trust.html) method for this. At the place in your view where you want the HTML output, write `m.trust( '<span class="msg">Text goes here</span>' )` and you should be sorted.

Comment: This solved my "How do I get mithril.js to process HTML in a JSON request?" Thanks.

Comment: Well spotted - fixed

Answer (score 0):

Mithril it's powerfull thanks to the virtual dom, in the **view** you if you want to create a html element you use:

```
m("htmlattribute.classeCss" , "value");
```

So in your case:

```
m("span.msg" , "Text goes here");
```

Answer (score -3):

Try creating a container you wish to hold your `span` in.
1. Use jQuery to select it.
2. On that selection, call the jQuery `.html()` method, and pass in your HTML string.
(`$('.container').html(//string-goes-here)`, for example)

You should be able to assign the inner HTML of the container with the string, resulting in the HTML element you want.

Docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString).

Comment: Fwiw, seems like you're using Mithril. This answer uses basic jQuery. I'm not sure if Mithril has HTML-to-element conversion, but this should solve your problem if you're willing to use jQuery.

Comment: This question is taged as a mithril.js question not a jQuery question.